# Plot multi-dimensional attributes to visualize result of k-means clustering

Tags: r, k-means

I am trying to implement k-means clustering using **Kmeans** in R. I have a data set **df** containing 4 columns (a,b,c,d). I have implemented k-means clustering using the following code:

```
result <- Kmeans(df,4,iter.max = 20, nstart = 25, method="euclidean")
```

When I try to plot the data set using the plot function it shows multiple graph with two attributes each.

```
plot(df, col=result$cluster)
```

But I want to plot all the attributes in the same graph. Is it possible? How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: You cannot plot 4 dimensions in a graph where each dimension is on a perpendicular axis. The best you can do is to plot 3D graphs with 3 dimensions. However, you can also use size, color, transparency or other attributes as dimensions.

Comment: Well, what do you want a four dimensional plot to look like? This doesn't seem to be a specific programming question since you don't seem to know what you want. If you have a general question seeking advice for data visualization, such questions are on topic for [stats.se], not Stack Overflow. At the very least on this site you should provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output.

Comment: You could plot your results in a [parallel coordinate plot](https://www.r-bloggers.com/parallel-coordinate-plots-for-discrete-and-categorical-data-in-r-a-comparison/). On the x axis you plot each coordinate as a category.